# Use Trades as Input for PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I'd like to use the [PerformanceAnalytics R package](http://braverock.com/brian/R/PerformanceAnalytics/html/PerformanceAnalytics-package.html) to view various metrics from a list of trades with profit values.  From looking at the documentation from the PerformanceAnalytics package that most functions are set up to use a time series of prices rather than an array of profit values (which of course can be negative).

Can PerformanceAnalytics be used on an array of profit values (from a backtest that might have several instruments in it for example)?  If not, is there a way to convert the profit values to a format that makes sense to input into most PerformanceAnalytics functions?

Answer (score 8):

If you've got a list of trades, I would first suggest using the [blotter](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/blotter/) package to enter those transactions and compute your cash P&L.  Then you can use the `tradeStats` function to see trade related statistics, or the `portfReturns` function to extract percent returns for your portfolio of symbols as a contribution to total account equity returns.  After calling portfReturns, all the functions in PerformanceAnalytics will have the inputs that they expect.

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there a way to convert the profit values to a format that makes sense to input into most PerformanceAnalytics functions?

Assume trade outcomes of 10, -5, 15,... for example, and starting equity of 100, then your equity time series will be 100, 110, 105, 120,... from which *returns* can be calculated.

Taken from the link you gave "In general, this library requires *return* (rather than price) data."